# Suppose $(a,b)=1$, then $(2a+b,a+2b)=1\text{ or }3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose $(a,b)=1$.  Let $d=(2a+b,a+2b)$.

Then $d=(2a+b)u+(a+2b)v=a(2u+v)+b(2v+u)$ where $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $(a,b)=1$, then $a(2u+v)+b(2v+u)=1$.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think your last equation is correct.  Since $d|2a+b$ and $d|a+2b$, you know that $d|a-b$ and $d|3a+3b$.

Comment: How did you get $d|a+b$ and $d|3a+3b$?

Comment: I used that $d|k$ and $d|l$ implies that $d|mk+nl$ for any integers m and n (with $m=1$ and $n=\pm1$).

Comment: Do you mind expanding on this?

Comment: If $d|k$ and $d|l$, then $k=rd$ and $l=sd$ gives $k+l=(r+s)d$ and $k-l=(r-s)d$, so $d|k+l$ and $d|k-l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct manipulation of gcd**

$\gcd(a+2b,2a+b) = \gcd(a+2b,(2a+b)-2(a+2b)) = \gcd(a+2b,-3b)$

$ | \gcd(a+2b,3) \gcd(a+2b,b) | 3 \gcd((a+2b)-2(b),b) = 3 \gcd(a,b) = 3$

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

Let $d=(a+2b,2a+b)$, so $d|3a$ since $d|2(2a+b)-(a+2b)$ and 
$d|3b$ 
since $d|2(a+2b)-(2a+b)$.

Therefore $d|(3a,3b)$.

Comment: I'm stuck trying to figure out how to compute $2(2a+b)-(a+2b)$.  I may be applying the Euclidean algorithm incorrectly...or are you eyeballing it?

Comment: Note: $\, 3a = 2(2a+b)-(a+2b) = 2A-B\,$ can be discovered *algorithmically* by inverting the linear map - see my answer (where $a,b$ are written $x,y)$.

Comment: @nhru if $d|a+2b$ then $d|-(a+2b)$ and if $d|2a+b$ then $d|2(2a+b)$ . By the comments you can infer now that $d|2(2a+b)-(a+2b)$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ Specialize the method below:  $\rm\,(x,y)\mapsto (2x+y,x+2y) =: (X,Y)\,$ has   $\, \det = 3,\,$ i.e.

$\qquad\begin{pmatrix} 2 & \rm 1 \\\\ \rm 1 & \rm 2 \end{pmatrix}\ \begin{pmatrix} x \\\\ \rm y \end{pmatrix}\ =\ \begin{pmatrix} X \\\\ \rm Y\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \begin{array} \rm\ 3\ x\ \ \ =\ \ \ \rm 2\ X \ - \ Y \\\\ \rm 3\ y\ =\ \rm\  - X + 2\ Y \end{array} $

**Theorem**  $\ $ If $\rm\,(x,y)\overset{A}\mapsto (X,Y)\,$ is linear then $\: \rm\gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y)\mid \Delta \gcd(x,y),\,\ \Delta = \det A$

**Proof** $\ $ Inverting the linear map $\rm\,A\,$ by [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) (multiplying by the adjugate) yields

$$\rm \begin{eqnarray} a\ x\, +\, b\ y &=&\rm X\\ \\ \rm c\ x\, +\, d\ y &\ =\ &\rm Y\end{eqnarray}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad \begin{array} \rm\Delta\ x\ \ \ =\ \ \ \rm d\ X\, -\, b\ Y \\\\ \rm\Delta\ y\ =\ \rm -c\ X\, +\, a\ Y \end{array}\ ,\quad\ \Delta\ =\ ad-bc\qquad $$

Hence, by RHS system, $\rm\ n\ |\ X,Y\ \Rightarrow\ n\ |\ \Delta\:x,\:\Delta\:y\ \Rightarrow\ n\ |\ gcd(\Delta\:x,\Delta\:y)\ =\ \Delta\ gcd(x,y)\:.$
In particular $\rm\ n = \gcd(X,Y) \mid \Delta\, \gcd(x,y).\ $

Further, by LHS system $\rm\,n\mid x,y\ \Rightarrow\ n\mid X,Y\ \Rightarrow\ n\mid\gcd(X,Y).$
In particular $\rm\ n = gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y).\ \ \ $  **QED**

Comment: I haven't seen using determinant here, could you explain how the determinant is 3? or what is the matrix that you are taking the determinant of?

Comment: @Wishingwell I added further details.

Comment: This answer might also be related to Smith normal form: the hypothesis implies that the map $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \end{bmatrix} : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, and then we want to know something about the image of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.  By writing $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ in the form $P D Q$ where $P, Q \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $D$ is diagonal, we can conclude the image of $x^t A$ equals the image of $x^t P D$; and there's an obvious relation between the entries of $D$ and $\det A = \det D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$d=\gcd(a+2b, 2a+b).$$
$$\Rightarrow d|a+2b, d|2a+b.$$
$$\rightarrow d|2(a+2b), d| 2a+b.$$
Now use this result that if $d=\gcd(a, b), d|a, d|b\ \text{then}\ d|a\pm b$.
So,
$$d|2a+4b-2a-b.$$
$$\Rightarrow d|3b.$$
Also $$\Rightarrow d|3a.$$
$$\therefore d|(3a, 3b) \Rightarrow d= 1\ \text{or} \ 3. (\because (a, b)=1.)$$