# If an integer $a$ is coprime with an integer $b$, then will the integer $a$ also be coprime with the integer $9a + b$?

Tags: prime-numbers

If an integer $a$ is coprime with an integer $b$, then will the integer $a$ also be
coprime with the integer $9a + b$ ?

Comment: Notice that if $d|a$ and $d|(9a+b)$, then $d|b$ since $b=(9a+b)-9a$; so $d=1$ if $d\in N$.

Answer (score 4):

If $1=ma+nb$, then $1=(m-9n)a+n(9a+b)$.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity for context.

Comment: Using Bezout here is a overkill, since it can be done simply by divisibility. Indeed, it is true in any ring (not only rings satisfying Bezout's identity).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The linear map $\,(a,b)\to (a,9a\!+\!b)\,$ has det $=\color{#c00}1,\ $ [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649446/242) $\ \gcd(a,9a\!+\!b)\mid \color{#c00}1\cdot \gcd(a,b)$