# Question about exercise 14 on p.14 of Nathanson's Elementary Methods in Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am revising some elementary number theory using Nathanson's book. My answer to question $14$ on page $14$ (see image) is $u = 5u' -3v'$, $v=-3u'+2v'$. Nathanson suggests that $u=u'$, $v=v'$.

Did I hit an error ( there are quite a lot, see [Teaching Blog](http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/previous-courses/507-errata/), or am I wrong? If I am wrong then please explain Nathanson's answer.

[image: exercises page 14 Nathanson EM in NT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u = pu' +qv'$$ $$v=ru'+sv'$$

**Note** $\,\,\gcd(u',v')|u\,\,$ *and* $\,\,\gcd(u',v')|v\,\,$. So, $\,\,\gcd(u',v')|\gcd(u,v)$

Similarly you can show this the other side.

Comment: Correct, I misread the GCD notation, am working in different books...

Comment: @ndroock1 A *crucial* point is that $\,p,q,r,s\,$ are not just any rationals but are *integers* (why?). For the argument to be convincingly correct this must be *explicitly* mentioned (and justified). See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/649446/242) for details, and a generalization, viz. **Theorem**  $\ $ If $\rm\,(x,y)\overset{A}\mapsto (X,Y)\,$ is linear then $\: \rm\gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y)\mid \Delta \gcd(x,y),\,\ \Delta = \det A\ \ $

Comment: What am I missing that allows one to write u and v in this way?