# Proving fraction is irreducible

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

**Example:** 
  The fraction $\frac{4n+7}{3n+5}$ is irreducible for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, because $3(4n+7) - 4(3n+5) = 1$ 
and if $d$ is divisor of $4n+7$ and $3n+5$, it divides $1$, so $d=1$.

I want to know if there is some **general method** of finding $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, 
so that $$x(an+b) + y(cn+d) = 1$$ when $(an+b, cn+d) = 1$, instead of trial and error,

 or some quicker and easier way (for not so pretty fractions) for determining whether it is irreducible.

Comment: Heard of eulidian gcd algorithm ?

Comment: Yes, but can you please show how to use it, on some example .. ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649446/242).

Comment: @someone first do you see why $\gcd(a, b)$ will be same as $\gcd(a-b, b)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, no knowledge in linear algebra, should've mentioned that ..

Comment: You don't need to know linear algebra, just use elimination to solve for $x$ and $y$ there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde *not* a dupe of that since here $n$ is an indeterminate.

Comment: @rsadhvika well yes, but that is just trial and error again, isn't it ?

Comment: It isn't. You may google to get hang of it, but I'll show you quick how to work it with an example

Comment: Suppose you want to find the $\gcd$ of $42$ and $15$. Hmm.. can you tell me your approach first ? :)

Comment: Find minimum of exponents in prime factorization ?

Comment: Yes, may be do it using your method first. After that I'll show you euclid; then you will appreciate why euclid is cool ;)

Comment: yeah, I get it that we can use euc. alg. for constants, but can you do it on fraction I posted as an example ?
Or on something not so obvious .. ?

Comment: Notice that when you replace $n$ with an integer, both numerator and denominator evaluate to integers. So we're good

Comment: Please clarify if you are assuming that $\,(an+b,cn+d) = 1\,$ for *all* $\,n.\ \ $

Comment: Yes, yes I'm ..

Comment: Sorry fot not making it clear ..

Comment: @someone just take a leap of faith and apply euclid gcd algorithm on $(4n+7, 3n+5)$

Comment: Well, I don't know how, can you be awesome and do it, please ?

Comment: Sure, but you will have to do the algebra :) As a start do  : $$4n+7 - (3n+5)$$

Comment: That gives $n+2$, so $$\gcd(4n+7, 3n+5) = \gcd(n+2, 3n+5)$$

Comment: See if you can guess what next step can be :)

Comment: Ooh okay, I had in mind long division :D
I get it from your and other answer .. Thank you!

Comment: Np :) do get back if smthng not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering your question, I will just give the following two facts:

**Let $\gcd(a,b) = g$**

> 1. $g$ is the smallest positive integer such that $ax+by = g$ for any integers $x,y$.
> 2. $$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a+bx, b) = \gcd(a,b+ax)$$

The proof of these two is elementary. In fact, it can be found somewhere here in this website.

Now, **Euclidean Algorithm** is used to find $g$ in $(1)$. How to apply this algorithm? you may refer to [this website](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/euclid.html) for more information.

In our case, the fraction is irreducible *if and only if* the greatest common divisor $g$ of the numerator and denominator is $1$. We can use the Euclidean Algorithm to find it, thought, and check.

**Why do we need (2)?**, Okay, this fact might be used as a shortcut to find $g$ in many occasions. For example, if I am given the following fraction and asked to prove it is irreducible: $$\frac{3n+4}{18n+25}$$ then I can use this shortcut as follows: $$\gcd(3n+4,18n+25) = \gcd(3n+4, (18n+25) -6(3n+4)) =  \gcd(3n+4,1) = 1$$

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Oh, you are welcome. :)

Comment: @someone Euclid isn't needed to eliminate $n$ from $\,18n\!+\!25\equiv 0\equiv 3n\!+\!4\pmod{\!d}\ $ See my link on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yeah, I see how to do it without euclid

Comment: @MagedSaeed Kinda off topic, but can this be used effectively for higher exponents than $1$ ? 
Polynomials is what I'm referring to.
Just looking for yes or no answer, I'll work it out why ..

Comment: @someone 
When equations require only Integer solutions, like ours here, it is called Diophantine equations. They are named after the greek mathematician Diophantus who is the first to study such topic. In our case, $ax+by=c$, it is easy to solve it. But for higher degrees and other forms, it might be very hard to do. In fact, these types of equations are considered one the purest, and may be hardest, topics of mathematics.

Comment: @MagedSaeed Oh, okay, I'll look into it .. Thanks for detailed answer ..

Comment: Oh you are more than welcome. :))

Comment: @MagedSaeed I'm just getting into number theory ..

Comment: I am sure You will enjoy it. Just keep practicing and be in touch with each topic.

Comment: @MagedSaeed Hey, just needed to get back on this,
$(a, b) = (a, ax + by) = (ax + by, a)$ is not true in general, right ?
But is it true that $(a, b)  |  (a, ax + by)$ and is equal when $ax + by \le |b|$ ?
Similary for $(ax + by, b)$ ..
Thanks.

Comment: @someone no it is true in general. Why do you say otherwise? do you have a counterexample? Moreover, this might be a typo but it is written as follows: $(a,b)=(a,b+ax) = (a+by,b)$

Comment: $(5, 10) \ne (2 \times 5 + 10, 10)$, right ?
Maybe you misread my comment ..

Comment: let $a = 5, b = 10, x = 2, y = 3$. We have $(5,10) = (5+10*2, 10) = (5,10+5*3) = 5$. Got it?

Comment: Just read my comment again, please.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about another case. I see.

Comment: It is true that $(a,b)|(a,ax+by)$. For the other case, I need to check.

Comment: Okay, thats good enough, thanks.

Comment: The first case can be proved as follows: $(a,ax+by)=(a,ax+by-ax) = (a,by)$. Now, $(a,b)|b \implies (a,b)|by \implies (a,b)|(a,by)$.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, for $a,b,c,d
> \in\Bbb N$, the following statements are equivalent:
>   $(i)$ there are integers $x,y$ s.t. $x(an+b)+y(cn+d)=1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$;
>   $(ii)$ $ad-bc$ divides $\gcd(a,c)$;
>   $(iii)$ $|ad-bc|  =\gcd(a,c)$.
>   Note also that any of the statements $(i)$, $(ii)$, and $(iii)$ implies that
>  $(iv)$ the rational number $\frac{an+b}{cn+d}$ is in the lowest form for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Obviously $(ii)\iff (iii)$ because $\gcd(a,c)$ always divide $ad-bc$.  In the case $ad-bc\mid \gcd(a,c)$, we can take $x=-\frac{c}{ad-bc}$ and $y=\frac{a}{ad-bc}$.  So $(ii)\implies (i)$.  We now prove that $(i)\implies (ii)$.

Suppose that such $x$ and $y$ exist.  Then,
$$ax+cy=0\wedge bx+dy=1.$$
That is, $(x,y)$ is an integer solution to
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Observe that the determinant $ad-bc$ of $\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$ cannot be $0$ (otherwise $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are proportional, and so $an+b$ and $cn+d$ are also proportional).  That is, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible and
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-c\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
So $(x,y)=\frac{1}{ad-bc}(-c,a)$.  That is, $ad-bc\mid c$ and $ad-bc\mid a$.  So $ad-bc\mid \gcd(a,c)$.

---

In your example, $a=4$, $b=7$, $c=3$, and $d=5$.  So, $ad-bc=-1 \mid \gcd(a,c)$, and we can take $x=-\frac{c}{ad-bc}=3$ and $y=\frac{a}{ad-bc}=-4$.

I should like to mention that $(iv)$ is not equivalent to any of the statements $(i)$, $(ii)$, and $(iii)$.  The rational numbers of the form $\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}$ is reduced for any $n\in \Bbb N$, but it does not meet $(i)$, $(ii)$, or $(iii)$ (i.e., $(a,b,c,d)=(2,1,2,3)$, so $\gcd(a,c)=2$, but $ad-bc=4\nmid\gcd(a,c)$).  However, $(iv)$ is equivalent to the condition that for any prime divisor $p$ of $ad-bc$, there does not exist $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $p$ divides both $an+b$ and $cn+d$.

Comment: Never studied linear algebra, but I guess I can use this as a shortcut without knowing why it's working ..

Comment: Why do you assume that the same $x$ and $y$ work for all $n,\,$ i.e. that they don't depend on $n$?