# If $ \gcd(a,b) = 1$ prove that $ \gcd(2a+b, a+2b) = 1$ or $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649433/suppose-a-b-1-then-2ab-a2b-1-text-or-3/) question, some other related questions and answers for solving this problem. However, I tried to solve it using a different approach.

Let, $ \gcd(2a+b, a+2b) = d$
Assume $2a+b = qd\tag{1}$
and so $b = qd - 2a$
If we replace b with this in $a+2b$, we get $a+2b = 2qd - 3a$

We know, $\gcd(a,b) = 1 $. Let, $\gcd(a,qd)=m$. So $a=mn$ and $qd=lm$. In equation (1), $2a+b=qd$ or $b=qd−2a=lm−2mn=m(l−2n)$. That means $m|b$ and so $\gcd(a,b)=m$ which is not true. So, $ \gcd(a, qd) = 1$.

Thus $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)$ = $\gcd(qd,2qd-3a)$ = $\gcd(qd,2qd-3)$. Since $\gcd(2,3) = 1, \gcd(qd,3) = 1$ or $3$ will be the answer.
Is this correct?

Comment: This is hard to follow.

Comment: How do you get gcd(a,qd)=1 from equation $(1)$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah We know, $\gcd(a,b)=1$. If $\gcd(a,qd)$ is not 1, then let, $gcd(a,qd) = m$. So $a = mn$ and $qd = lm$. In equation (1), $2a+b = qd$ or $b = qd - 2a = lm - 2mn = m(l-2n)$. That means $m|b$ and so $\gcd(a,b) = m$ which is not true. So, $\gcd(a,qd) = 1$

Comment: @Aqua Which part is hard to follow?

Comment: I follow everything until the last line in which you write $\gcd(2a + b, a + 2b) = \gcd(qd, 2qd - 3).$ I suspect that the latter should be $\gcd(qd, 2qd - 3a),$ correct?

Comment: But this implies that $\gcd(2a + b, a + 2b) = \gcd(qd, -3) = 1$ or $3$ since $3$ is prime.

Comment: @Carlo You are correct, but $a$ was omitted because I already proved $\gcd(qd,a) = 1$, thus $\gcd(qd,2qd-3a) = \gcd(qd,2qd-3)$. Since $a$ and $qd$ have nothing in common, $a$ can be omitted and I focus on $qd$ and 3. Your second comment is correct.

Comment: @Carlo I edited the proof after your comment

Comment: "Since gcd(a,b)=1, from equation (1), we get gcd(a,qd)=1"  How so?  If we can do that in our heads we don't really need to do this proof in the first place.

Comment: @fleablood I explained it in one comment. Alright, I'll add it to the proof.

Comment: You are  very generally making conclusions of which *every* single one of them is harder to verify and less intuitively obvious than the entire thing you are trying to prove in the first place.

Comment: @fleablood "Every single one of them" - can you give me some examples?

Comment: Sure, you claimed that because $2a+b=qd$ that therefore $\gcd(a,b) \implies \gcd(a,qd)=1$.  Thats far from obvious.  Then you claim that as $\gcd(2a+b, a+2b) = \gcd(qd, 2qd -3a)$ then $\gcd(2,3)=1\implies \gcd(qd,2qd-3a)=1,3$.  *Large* leaps.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the suggestions. I tried to remove the large leaps but seem to have found a flaw in the proof. I will try to solve it tomorrow.

Comment: Why not do it the straight forward way?  $2(2a+b) -(a+2b) =3a$ so $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)|3a$.  ANd $2(a+2b)-(2a+b) =3b$ so $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)|3b$.  If $p$ is a prime factor other than $3$ of $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)$ then $p|a$ and $p|b$ but that contradicts $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  And if $3^2|\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)$ then $3|a$ and $3|b$ which is a contradiction. So the only possible prime factor of $\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)$ is *maybe* but not nesc $3$ and if it *is* a prime factor it's only to the single power.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks. I knew this proof already, though your proof has some new information. I was just trying something new, wondering if that would work.

Answer (score 2):

Choose integers $r,s$ such that $ar+bs=1$. Then

$$ (2a+b)(2r-s) + (a+2b)(2s-r) = 3(ar+bs) = 3. $$

So if $g=\gcd(2a+b,a+2b)$, then $g \mid 3$. Hence, $g=1$ or $3$.

Moreover, from $3 \mid \big((2a+b)+(a+2b)\big)$, we have $3 \mid (2a+b)$ if and only if $3 \mid (a+2b)$. Further, note that $3 \mid (2a+b)$ if and only if $3 \mid \big(3a-(2a+b)\big)=a-b$. Therefore,

$$ \gcd(2a+b,a+2b) = \begin{cases} 1 & \:\mbox{if}\: 3 \nmid (a-b); \\ 3 & \:\mbox{if}\: 3 \mid (a-b). \end{cases} $$

Comment: I noticed it that 3|2a+b when 3 divides the difference between a and b. Thanks for writing it coherently.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's analysis seems valid to me.  However, I don't think it is the intended answer.  If $d$ is a common factor of both $2a + b$ and $a + 2b$, then it is a factor of their sum, which equals $3a + 3b = 3(a+b).$

Thus any common factor of $2a + b$ and $a + 2b$ will either be a factor of $3$ or a factor of $(a+b).$